# Where can I find documentation for the JNI package in Oracle Forms?

Tags: oracle, java-native-interface, oracleforms

Oracle Forms provides a PL/SQL package named `JNI` to interact with Java. Does anyone know where I may find this package's documentation? I have only been able to glean parts of its API by reading the existing PL/SQL libraries that come with Oracle Forms.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[These Oracle Java Importer docs](http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/A97335_02/apps.102/a86202/appc.htm) say:

> The ORA_JAVA package is a helper
>   package that provides error handling,
>   array, and persistency support. (There
>   is also an internal JNI package used
>   to call Java methods, but you do not
>   need to know the contents of this
>   package or call it directly.)

The reference for ORA_JAVA is [here](http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/A97335_02/apps.102/a86202/appc.htm#630498).

Comment: Thank you very much! That saved me a lot of effort.